# How to check SQL Server connection to a database in WIX

Tags: database, session, wix

I'm using WIX to build an installer. Now I want to detect if my database is connected by other session, if yes, throw an error.

Could anybody show me how to do that using WIX?
I know it's easy using C#, but don't know how to do it using WIX, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using Custom Action. Below is piece of code, hope it helps others.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult DoCheck(Session ssion)
{
    ...
    if (CheckDBInUse(...))
    {
        ...
        session["DBINUSE"] = "Y"; // Set flag
        ...
    }
}

private static bool CheckDBInUse(...)
{
    // SELECT host_process_id FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS WHERE DATABASE_ID = DB_ID('{0}')"
    // do check
}
```

In WXS file:

```
<control ...>
<publish Event="SpawnDialgo" Value="DBInUseDlg">DBINUSE = "Y"</publish>
</control>

<Dialog Id="DBInuseDlg" ....>
  <control>....
</Dialog>
```